# Checking brackets nesting in a string

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge

I took a training challenge on Codility that checks for the proper nesting of brackets in a string. The brackets to be checked are `{,},(,),[,]`. I have written the following Java program which passes in O(n) time and space, but I have a feeling that the extra space I use can be reduced. Also I think that there must be a data structure that can handle this scenario more efficiently. Using an ArrayList instead of an array might help. What I need here is a critique of my code.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
class Solution {
    public int solution(String S) {
        char[] stack = new char[S.length()];
        int last = -1;
        HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put('}', '{');
        hm.put(')', '(');
        hm.put(']', '[');
        for(int i=0; i<S.length(); i++){
            char next = S.charAt(i);
            if(next == '}' || next == '{' || next == ')' || next == '(' ||
            next == ']' || next == '[')
            {
                if(last!=-1 && hm.containsKey(next) && stack[last] == hm.get(next)){
                    last--;
                }
                else{
                    last++;
                    stack[last] = S.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        if(last == -1){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Naming

- Class name: `Solution` A solution for what?
- Method name: `solution` - again I ask: **Solution for what?**
- Parameter name: `S` - And what on earth is `S`? Parameter names are by convention named beginning with a lowercase letter.

None of these three names are descriptive names. It is easier to read and understand code when the names tell a bit about what it is that the code does. Now, naming things are hard, and something that programmers do a lot. For this case, consider names such as `BracketNestingVerifier`, `verify` and `input`. You might even be able to come up with better names.

#### General things

- Use **Generics** for your `HashMap`. Since Java 1.5, it's been possible to define which kind of HashMap it is. Is it a HashMap of `<Integer, String>`? `<String, Byte>`? No, in your case; it's `HashMap<Character, Character>`
- Why do the method return an `int` when it would make much more sense to return a true/false `boolean`? Returning a boolean allows you to simplify the end of your method

  ```
  if (last == -1) { // note the fixed spacing ;)
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
  ```

  To simply `return (last == -1);`

#### Spacing

I find that code like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<S.length(); i++){
```

Is much more readable if you use spacing (and a better variable name for `S` of course)

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
```

#### Algorithm

Now, about that algorithm... You have a variable called `stack` and yet it isn't a stack structure, it's only an array. Using a somewhat real stack structure can be helpful. In the code below, I have used the `LinkedList` class to provide this structure (Even though there is also a `Stack` class, I like the `Deque` interface and wanted to go with `LinkedList`).

In this code, I have improved the variable names, the return type, and I am using a `HashSet` to store all "special" characters in. The `contains` method of a HashSet is performing in constant speed, so you should not experience any significant lack of performance. I noticed that in your if-statement, you had hard-coded the values that were put into your `HashMap`, this is what made me want to add the `HashSet`.

To make this work, I had to flip the key/values of your HashMap. The key is now the starting character, and the target is the expected ending character.

The loop through the string here is pretty simple and straight-forward:

- Have we waited for this character? If so, remove it from the list of expected characters we are waiting for (The "stack")
- If the above is not true, does this character have a matching ending character? If it does, add it to the stack
- Again, if the above also is not true, is this character regarded as a special character? If it is, then we know here already that we have failed so we can return from the method.

```
public boolean simonsVerify(String input) {
    HashMap<Character, Character> matches = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    matches.put('{', '}');
    matches.put('(', ')');
    matches.put('[', ']');

    Set<Character> specialChars = new HashSet<Character>();
    Deque<Character> expected = new LinkedList<Character>();
    for (Entry<Character, Character> ee : matches.entrySet()) {
        specialChars.add(ee.getKey());
        specialChars.add(ee.getValue());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char next = input.charAt(i);
        Character expect = expected.peekLast();
        if (expect != null && expect == next) {
            expected.removeLast();
        }
        else if (matches.containsKey(next)) {
            expected.addLast(matches.get(next));
        }
        else if (specialChars.contains(next)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the testing (with JUnit) I used, for both your original code and also for my method:

```
@Test
public void testVerifying() {
    assertTrue(verify("{,},({,}),[,]"));

    assertFalse(verify("{(,},({,}),[,]"));
    assertFalse(verify("{,)},({gfdgfd}),[,]"));
    assertFalse(verify("{(,}),({,}),[,]"));

    assertTrue(verify("{,},(,),[[,]]"));
    assertTrue(verify("{,},(,),[,]"));
    assertTrue(verify("{{,}},(,),[,]"));
    assertTrue(verify("{,},((,)),[,]"));
    assertTrue(verify("{,},(,),[,]"));
    assertTrue(verify("(), {{{,}}},(,),[,]"));
}
```

There might even be a better way to do this algorithm, this is just my way.

Comment: Well, this was a coding challenge at Codility.com and the return type had to be an int to pass the test cases :). So I am not "entirely" at fault :D. But all your points definitely make a lot of sense. I have not been an active part of the online community, but I think it will definitely help me learn a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: Why no spaces in "i=0"?

Comment: @AlexisWilke Because I missed them :) Thanks!

Comment: @Pankaj Just added a review of the algorithm itself.

Comment: `specialChars` should just be a set of the closing delimiters, and should be renamed accordingly. You would only reach `if (specialChars.contains(next))` when `next` is not an opening delimiter.

Answer (score 6):

Using an array as a simplistic stack can work, as long as you are confident that your input is reasonably sized.  However, I think your code is repetitive: the giant `if` condition fails to take advantage of the `HashMap`.

```
public class DelimiterMatcher {
    private static final HashMap<Character, Character> DELIMITERS = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    static {
        DELIMITERS.put('(', ')');
        DELIMITERS.put('{', '}');
        DELIMITERS.put('[', ']');
    }
    private static final Collection<Character> CLOSING_DELIMITERS = DELIMITERS.values();

    public static boolean hasMatchingDelimiters(String s) {
        char[] stack = new char[s.length() / 2 + 1];
        int last = 0;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                char next = s.charAt(i);
                Character closingDelimiter;
                if (next == stack[last]) {
                    // Found expected closing delimiter.  Pop it from the stack.
                    --last;
                } else if ((closingDelimiter = DELIMITERS.get(next)) != null) {
                    // Found opening delimiter.  Push the corresponding closing
                    // delimiter onto the stack.
                    stack[++last] = closingDelimiter;
                } else if (CLOSING_DELIMITERS.contains(next)) {
                    // Found unexpected closing delimiter
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return last == 0;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException tooManyOpenOrCloseDelimiters) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add different approach for the given problem. I was thinking that it is the typical problem using the stack so I am adding an approach that is using the system stack and recursion instead the user stack. I incorporated the great idea of the maps from the previous answer.

```
private static final Map<Character, Character> DELIMITERS = new HashMap<Character, Character>();

static {
    DELIMITERS.put('(', ')');
    DELIMITERS.put('{', '}');
    DELIMITERS.put('[', ']');
}
private static final Collection<Character> CLOSING_DELIMITERS = DELIMITERS.values();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "{(65)45dfa";
    final CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(s);

    System.out.println(new CorrectBrackets().areDelimitersCorrect(CharacterIterator.DONE, it, it.current()));
}

public boolean areDelimitersCorrect(Character closingDelimiter, CharacterIterator it, Character currentCharacter) {
    boolean correctDelimitersInside = true;
    while (currentCharacter != CharacterIterator.DONE && correctDelimitersInside) {
        if ( currentCharacter.equals(closingDelimiter) ){
            return true;
        }
        //If it is not my closing delimiter but it is some other closing delimiter then it is wrong
        if ( CLOSING_DELIMITERS.contains(currentCharacter) ){
            return false;
        }
        //If there is an opening one lets recurse.
        if (DELIMITERS.containsKey(currentCharacter)) {
            correctDelimitersInside = areDelimitersCorrect(DELIMITERS.get(currentCharacter), it, it.next());
        }
        currentCharacter = it.next();
    }

    //Check if all the inside was correct plus if I am closing correctly.
    return correctDelimitersInside && currentCharacter.equals(closingDelimiter);
}
```