# Bracket Pair Validation

Tags: java, strings

Validate that the following bracket pairs `[]`, `{}`, `()` open and close successfully in a candidate String.

Valid String Example: `"[{()}]"` should be evaluated as `true` because no "outer" open bracket is closed before an "inner" open bracket.

Invalid String Example: `"[f{o]o}"`

I would appreciate feedback on my implementation:

- Is there a case I'm missing?
- Is there a cleaner way to validate bracket pairs?
- Are there any particular performance concerns I'm ignoring?
- I have hard-coded my bracket values. What if I want to add, say, ten more bracket values...is there a cleaner way to implement the open/close relationship? Use a `Map`, perhaps?

```java
public boolean validateBracketPairs(final String string) {
        final Stack<Character> bracketStack = new Stack<>();
        for (final char character : string.toCharArray()) {
            if ('{' == character || '[' == character || '(' == character) {
                bracketStack.push(character);
            }

            else if (!bracketStack.empty() &&
                    (('{' == bracketStack.peek() && '}' == character)
                        || ('[' == bracketStack.peek() && ']' == character)
                        || ('(' == bracketStack.peek() && ')' == character)))  {
                bracketStack.pop();
            }

            else if ('}' == character || ']' == character || ')' == character) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return bracketStack.empty();
    }
```

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/41695/62058

Comment: Looks like a xy-problem. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, so I've got a few suggestions.

First, instead of making ourselves worry about non-bracket characters, let's trim them out:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^\\[\\]\\{\\}\\(\\)]", "");
```

You'll have to remove the `final` modifier, which I can't see a reason for anyway. Also, you never actually caused an error if `character` wasn't a bracket, so the code still ends up working the same. It's just less to worry about.

*Note: Technically, since this code ignores all non-bracket characters, this statement isn't necessary. If you comment it out, the rest of the code should still work fine. Still, I like explicitly saying, in code, that my thing ignores your petty brackets and mustaches.*

Second, let's define a `private static final Map<Character, Character> MATCHING_CHARS`<sup>1</sup> to store the pairs, instead of hardcoding them. That way, instead of checking if something matches one of three hard-coded brackets, we can do this:

```
if (MATCHING_CHARS.containsKey(character)) {
```

And instead of `peek()`ing once per bracket, we do it a flat rate of once:

```
else if (!bracketStack.empty() &&
    MATCHING_CHARS.get(bracketStack.peek()) == character) {
```

Note that since `get` returns `null` when the key isn't there, it automagically doesn't give a crap if the character isn't in `MATCHING_CHARS`! (and also doesn't match)

And finally, we replace your last `if` with:

```
else if (MATCHING_CHARS.containsValue(character)) {
```

Whew! Much simpler. Now, unless you plan to synchronize that regex we used at the beginning and the map for any brackets you add in the future, I suggest we do this:

```
private static final String REMOVE_REGEX = "[^\\" + String.join("\\", 
    MATCHING_CHARS.values().appendAll(MATCHING_CHARS.keys()) // every bracket
) + "]"; //for brackets 'a', 'b', 'c' should be "[^\\a\\b\\c]"
```

Then we use that in the place of the regex from before.

Actually, I don't suggest we do that awful mess of a line, I suggest we use a language where it's easier to get the behavior I'm looking for and doesn't require ugly hacks, but whatever. Ya make do with what you've got.

Now, one last tip: Don't name things `string`. Name it `checking` or `toCheck` or something that describes its purpose. Java's a statically-typed language; we can tell that it's a `String` without you naming it that.